# Magento: How do I setup additional state/status-triggered transaction mails?

Tags: magento

Our Magento store (CE 1.8.1.0) currently sends these 3 automatic standard transaction mails to our customers:

-New Order

-Payment Received

-Shipped

---

Our business is demanding the following statuses (see according states in brackets)

-01_Ordered                (state:NEW)

-02_Paid                   (state:PROCESSING)

-03_Order transmitted      (state:PROCESSING)

-04_Production finished   (state:PROCESSING)

-05_Quality check finished  (state:PROCESSING)

-06_Shipped from factory   (state:SEA FREIGHT)

-07_Arrival Germany        (state:COMPLETE)

-08_Arrival Customer (state:COMPLETE)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that sales emails are triggered by new STATES. This means we would need to

a) setup the additional state "SEA FREIGHT" (the other 3 are standard Magento states)

b) setup automatic sending of an additional transactional mail triggered by the state "SEA FREIGHT"

---

Is this correct?
If yes, what's the way to solve this?

Comment: Why not change the order status and send the email in the same time? To complete, if you just want to send an email, it is more easier to add a new status "sea freight" in the processing state than add a new state.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically trigger another transaction mail when a certain a order has a status? How do I do that?

Comment: How do you update order status from "processing" to "sea freight"? manually? import file? api?